# Mount, fstab && noob

Tags: ubuntu, ntfs, ext3

Дано:

1. OS: Ubuntu 11.04
2. Разделы: 2 ext3 (корневой и дополнительный), 1 swap, 3 ntfs

Что нужно:

1. Чтобы ntfs разделы монтировались автоматически при запуске системы
2. Чтобы все ntfs разделы монтировалсь от моего основного пользователя (uid=1000, faiwer), а не от root-а
3. Чтобы все разделы монтировались по UUID, а не по /dev/sdY
4. Чтобы дополнительный ex3 раздел тоже монтировался

Что я сделал:

1. Fstab - http://pastebin.com/QivgDtPn
2. Разделы - http://pastebin.com/uYRQyAe6

Проблема:

1. В наутилусе все разделы дублируются. Одни, видимо, по /dev/sdX, другие мои, уже отмонтированные
2. Дополнительный ext3 раздел не монтируется, ругается при запуске системы, но ошибка непонятна, ибо русс.версия а вместо букв квадраты ;)
3. Я совсем запутался =(

P.S. А можно как-нибудь проверить настройки fstab не перегружая ПК? :)

Answer (score 1):

Собственно пока не ответ, но все же пропиши:

```
locale -a  //Узнаешь какие локали установлены
LANG=en_US.utf8 //Наверное у тебя такая локаль есть))
```

Теперь примонтируй ext3 и посмотри, что mount пишет в поток ошибок
Проверить настройки автоматом на валидность вроде бы нельзя, а проверить как все монтируется можно так:

```
mount - a
mount
```

Comment: с ext3 уже разобрался. Сейчас у меня такой fstab - http://pastebin.com/vkkWfhFX . Как можно заметить, все ntfs разделы монтируются по /dev/sdX. Если же монтировать по UUID (закоментировано), то nautilus отображает 3 ntfs смонтированных раздела (UUID), и 3 ссылки на монтирование /dev/sdX. Других проблем не осталось